# How do I insert a hash password into the database?

Tags: php

How will I be able to insert the hashed password into the database instead of cleartext?

(I have tried replacing the '?' with 'SHA2('?',256')').

Do include some explanation also, thanks!

```
$query= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `useracct` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?,?)");
$email = $_POST["email"];
$psswd = $_POST["passd"];
$name = $_POST["name"];

$query->bind_param('bb', $email, $psswd, $name);
if ($query->execute()) {
  echo "Query executed.";
}else{
  echo "Query error.";
}
```

Comment: You're inserting for 3 columns (`email`, `password`, `name`), but only have 2 placeholders and are only binding 2 values - that will fail the execute

Comment: `$psswd = hash($_POST["passd"]);` and the rest is almost same.

Comment: `echo "Querry error.";` that doesn't help you. `mysqli_error($con)` will.

Comment: @OP are you  sure you want to use `b`'s here? those are strings and not blobs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, and if your columns are blob types, your query may fail you later.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try:

```
$query= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `useracct` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$email = $_POST["email"];
$psswd = PASSWORD_HASH($_POST["passd"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$name = $_POST["name"];

$query->bind_param('bbb', $email, $psswd, $name);
if ($query->execute()) {
  echo "Query executed.";
} else{
  echo "Query error.";
}
```

I have used PHP's `PASSWORD_HASH` function to hash the password and this function is supported in PHP 5.5 and later. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Another way of hashing the password is `crypt()` function of PHP which is supported since PHP 4. More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: This is a *try this* answer. I noticed the edit, but it would be beneficial to give an explanation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `useracct` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?,?,?)"); //missing one parameter here
$email = $_POST["email"];
$psswd = $_POST["passd"]; 
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
$name = $_POST["name"];
$query->execute([$email, $hash, $name]);
```

Comment: can you give the world an explanation here please? thank you in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace below

```
$query->bind_param('bb', $email, $psswd, $name);
```

to

```
$query->bind_param('bbb', $email, $psswd, $name);
```

Since you are using three variables, you should use three datatypes also.

Comment: question is, *why* they should replace it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **PASSWORD_HASH** for hasing

```
$query= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `useracct` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$email = $_POST["email"];
$psswd = $_POST["passd"];
$name = $_POST["name"];

$query->bind_param('bbb', $email, PASSWORD_HASH($psswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $name);
if ($query->execute()) {
  echo "Query executed.";
}else{
  echo "Query error.";
}
```

For verification use

```
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$psswd = $_POST["passd"];
$psswd1 =password_hash("passwd");
```

use like this and in query use `$psswd1` instead of `$psswd`

Comment: Apart from the fact that this doesn't work, md5 is considered insecure nowadays and should not be used as a hash for passwords.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple answers on this, but I feel they cover the **how**, but not **why**. I will try to leave out details about database handlers or encryption functions, as they change over time.

The main point that the other answers demonstrate is that you want to create the hash in PHP, not in MySQL. The reason for this being if you create hash in MySQL, then PHP needs to send clear text password to MySQL, and this is just another vector that could be exploited by an attacker.

Then you save password as any other string. There are multiple ways to hash a password, and usually you would want to store hashed password and a salt.

For example:

```
$salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
$passwordHash = sha1('123456' . $salt);
```

Then your query would read something like:

```
INSERT INTO ... (..., password, salt) VALUES (..., $passwordHash, $salt)
```

This helps against finding out the password when the attacker knows hash of the password; the problem with storing plain hashes is it is susceptible to **rainbow table attacks**, where common strings are already mapped to their hashes, so it is possible to search the original string by its hash.

Edit: See Jay Blanchard's comment for a more up to date method using functions built in to PHP as of 5.5.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Sweet, didn't know about `password_hash`. Note that with `password_hash` no separate field for salt is required; the salt is stored in same field as the password. `password_verify` will automatically determine what part of the string is hash and what is salt.

Comment: Note that `random_bytes()` is a cryptographically secure method introduced in PHP 7, unlike `rand()`… Great to see all these improvements in latest releases. :-)